# Css add gradient to Element + Before

Tags: css, tooltip, gradient

I'm drawing a tooltip box with Css.
Now I would like to apply a gradient to the whole box including the triangle. But the gradient is always only applied to the box.

I tried to put the gradient into the after element, but that doesnt work either. I would just color the triangle in one color, but I need to be able to move it to other places too.

This isn't a duplicate question, as in other answers, the triangle is just colored in the end color of the gradient. But I would like the gradient to also apply to the triangle.

[image]

Here's an example:

```css
body {
  background-color: tomato;
}
#bubble {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 50px;
  width: 154px;
  height: 140px;
  padding: 0px;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
  -moz-border-radius: 6px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1em;
  font-weight: 500;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(rgba(223, 204, 206, 0.9) 0%, rgba(242, 144, 127, 1) 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(rgba(223, 204, 206, 0.9) 0%, rgba(242, 144, 127, 1) 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(223, 204, 206, 0.9) 0%, rgba(242, 144, 127, 1) 100%);
  / filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#e6dfccce', endColorstr='#f2907f', GradientType=0);
}
#bubble:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 15px 16px 0px;
  border-color: #FFFFFF transparent;
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  bottom: -15px;
  left: 59px;
}
#bubble > :first-child {
  margin-top: 19px;
}
.answerWrapper {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.answerWrapperText {
  width: 40px;
  height: 38px;
  color: #131313;
  border: solid 2px #131313;
}
.answerWrapper > :first-child {
  margin: 0 0 0 18px;
}
.answerWrapper > :nth-child(2) {
  margin: 0 18px 0 0;
}
.answerWrapperText p {
  margin: 0;
  margin-top: 9px;
}
```

```html
<div id="bubble">
  <p>Have you
    <br>chosen wisely&#8239;?</p>
  <div class="answerWrapper">
    <div class="answerWrapperText">
      <p id="yes">yes</p>
    </div>
    <div class="answerWrapperText">
      <p id="no">no</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tooltip/Speech bubble with a gradient background and arrow at top-center](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14602659/tooltip-speech-bubble-with-a-gradient-background-and-arrow-at-top-center)

Comment: @KiranShakya I've been looking at this, and as I've said in the question, I need the triangle to get the gradient color, to be able to move it to the leftside too. In the other question, the triangle is just colored in the last color of the gradient.

Comment: did you try clip-path?
`-webkit-clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 100% 0%, 100% 75%, 58% 75%, 50% 100%, 40% 75%, 0% 75%);
clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 100% 0%, 100% 75%, 58% 75%, 50% 100%, 40% 75%, 0% 75%);`

Comment: @KiranShakya i need to keep the round corners. Wondering to do it with canvas.

Comment: you can use svg vector too... round corner will be a piece of cake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So my solution is to draw it with canvas.

[image]

```js
var bubbleBackground;

function initCanvas () {
 bubbleBackground = document.createElement('canvas');
 bubbleBackground.id = "BubbleId";
 bubbleBackground.width = 184;
 bubbleBackground.height = 170;
 bubbleBackground.style.position = "absolute";
 document.body.appendChild(bubbleBackground);
}

function drawCanvas (drawDirection) {

 var ctx = document.getElementById('BubbleId').getContext("2d");

 //clear canvas before draw
 ctx.clearRect(0, 0, bubbleBackground.width, bubbleBackground.height);
 //set to draw normally
 ctx.globalCompositeOperation="source-over";

 var posX = 15;
 var posY = 15;
 ctx.roundRect(posX, posY, 154, 140, 6);
 ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)';
 ctx.fill();

 switch(drawDirection) {
    case "top":
        ctx.beginPath();
     ctx.moveTo(106,15);
     ctx.lineTo(78,15);
     ctx.lineTo(92,3);
     ctx.fill();
        break;
    case "right":
     ctx.beginPath();
     ctx.moveTo(169,71);
     ctx.lineTo(181,85);
     ctx.lineTo(169,99);
     ctx.fill();        
        break;
    case "bottom":
        ctx.beginPath();
     ctx.moveTo(78,155);
     ctx.lineTo(106,155);
     ctx.lineTo(92,167);
     ctx.fill();
        break;
    case "left":
        ctx.beginPath();
     ctx.moveTo(15,71);
     ctx.lineTo(15,99);
     ctx.lineTo(3,85);
     ctx.fill();
        break;
    default:
        console.log("no arrow")
 } 

 //draw gradient
 ctx.globalCompositeOperation="source-in";
 var grd=ctx.createLinearGradient(0,0,0,170);
 grd.addColorStop(0, 'rgba(223,204,206,0.9)');
 grd.addColorStop(1, 'rgba(242,144,127,1)');

 ctx.fillStyle=grd;
 ctx.fillRect(0,0,184,170);

}

CanvasRenderingContext2D.prototype.roundRect = function (x, y, width, height, radius) {
  if (width < 2 * radius) radius = width / 2;
  if (height < 2 * radius) radius = height / 2;
  this.beginPath();
  this.moveTo(x + radius, y);
  this.arcTo(x + width, y, x + width, y + height, radius);
  this.arcTo(x + width, y + height, x, y + height, radius);
  this.arcTo(x, y + height, x, y, radius);
  this.arcTo(x, y, x + width, y, radius);
  this.closePath();
  return this;
}

initCanvas();
drawCanvas("right");
```

Answer (score 1):

In this case you can't use border solution for the ":after", instead create another gradient and rotate the element.

```
#bubble:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  /* border-style: solid; */
  /* border-width: 15px 16px 0px; */
  /* border-color: #FFFFFF transparent; */
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  bottom: -10px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  /* background: red; */
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  z-index: -1;
  background: linear-gradient(130deg, rgba(223, 204, 206, 0.9) 0%, rgba(242, 144, 127, 1) 50%);
}
```

Here is the full example: [Codepen](http://codepen.io/jotavejv/pen/VKJRPP)